# visual studio 2013, 2015 how to show full file path

Tags: visual-studio, file, path

I am trying to find the setting in VS IDE to show full file path, and I found this solution, the right way to achieve my gold. It is source from msdn.microsoft.com.

Dung Le.

Comment: If simply hovering over the tab isn't enough ...

Comment: @Filburt It isn't enough when you have e.g. a whole bunch of (similar) App.configs and you are having to double-check which one you are on so you don't screw it up.

Answer (score 4):

Install the [**File Path On Footer**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.FilePathOnFooter) extension

Tested, Quick and easy. Download, double-click to install, restart Visual Studio IDE. Support for Visual Studio 2015, 2013, 2012, 2010

This lightweight extension lets you display the full path of the file at bottom of Visual Studio's Editor.

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been looking for the same thing as the OP and this is a good alternative to buying an extension like https://tabsstudio.com/ when you just want to easily glance and see which file is the one you are working on.